# Why WHOIS query get one IP in multi AS?

Tags: ip-address

I am query [WHOIS information](http://tool.chinaz.com/ipwhois?q=47.108.85.10):

but I find two AS number of the IP:

```
% Information related to \'47.104.0.0/13AS37963\'

route: 47.104.0.0/13
descr: Hangzhou Alibaba Advertising Co.,Ltd.
country: CN
origin: AS37963
mnt-by: MAINT-CNNIC-AP
last-modified: 2019-08-07T23:28:06Z
source: APNIC

% Information related to \'47.104.0.0/13AS45102\'

route: 47.104.0.0/13
descr: Alibaba (US) Technology Co., Ltd.
country: CN
origin: AS45102
mnt-by: MAINT-CNNIC-AP
last-modified: 2019-08-07T23:28:05Z
source: APNIC
```

as we know one IP only can exist in one AS, why there comes two?

Comment: I don't see the `47.104.0.0/13` prefix in `AS45102` at all. That may be something that has changed since the time that this question was posted, but as it stands the information listed is not correct. Reference [hurricane electric](https://bgp.he.net/AS45102#_prefixes) for more info. Strangely it could indicate BGP hijacking occuring (intentional or otherwise), but that would be a long bet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> as we know one IP only can exist in one AS

That's totally incorrect. An IP address (or better, a prefix) can be sourced from multiple ASNs. This is called *Anycast*.

Also, there could be an even more plausible explanation here: maybe someone forgot to delete one of the two route objects when the IP range was transferred from one to another, or they're in the process of transferring it. Not having a correct route object can lead to problems getting your prefixes routed by other networks. That's why routing registries allow for more than one route object for a prefix.